# Custom UICollectionViewLayout calls layoutAttributesForElementsInRect multiple times

Tags: ios7, ios6, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I created a custom `UICollectionViewLayout` which creates a two dimensional grid. Scrolling horizontal ant vertical works fine. There is just a problem if you test it on different `OS`.

If you get to the right or bottom border of the whole `UICollectionView` and `bounces` are turned on, on `iOS7` nothing happens. But when it gets to `iOS6` every time you drag the `UICollectionView` over the `bounds` size, the method `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect` will be called multiple times. This causes a massive `lag` because inside `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect` the layout is enumerating all views to get the views which should be displayed.

Does somebody know what causes this problem on `iOS6`

Answer (score 0):

Cache your layout attributes in prepareLayout. Loop through them and see what intersects in layoutAttributesForElementsInRect. Make a breakpoint in layoutAttributesForElementsInRect and ensure it's UIKit code triggering the call. If it's your own code triggering this call, see if you can avoid triggering it more than necessary. In my case this method is generally just used by UIKit to determine how to lay out the onscreen cells.